# Flask - Stripe - Firebase Auth

Tags: flask, firebase-authentication, stripe-payments

As of right now I have firebase auth (generic email/password) set up as well as a Stripe payment stream.

What is the most simple way to link a stripe customer id to the firebase auth user credentials?

Can I somehow force the user to use the same email address to have that as a unique id?

It does not seem that I can store additional info within the authentication process but I could be wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing the email variable from firebase auth to the stripe form.

I did this by {{ email }} and adding the "Data-email" field to the  provided base form code in their documentation.